# d3 stack bar chart in version 4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I read "Interactive Data Visualization for the web" by Scott Murray, but this book use d3 version3. I've tried to fix it, but some problems happen, and my code is below. I got errors about "y: Expected length, "NaN".", and maybe my stack function doesn't work. However, I don't know how to solve it. I need someone to help me.

```
 // declare variable
var svgWidth = 500,
    svgHeight = 300,
    svgData = [],
    maxValue = 16;

svgData = getData(svgData);    

// set stack color
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

// create stack layout
var stack = d3.stack();
stack(svgData);          

// define x,y scale
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
               .domain(d3.range(svgData[0].length))
               .rangeRound([0, svgWidth])
               .paddingInner(0.05),
    yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(svgData, function(d){
                       return d3.max(d, function(d){
                           d.y0 + d.y;
                       });
                })])
               .range([0, svgHeight])
               .clamp(true);

// create svg
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", svgWidth)
            .attr("height", svgHeight);

// add group and fill color for each row of data
var group = svg.selectAll("g")
               .data(svgData)
               .enter()
               .append("g")
               .style("fill", function(d, i){
                   return color(i);
                });

// add a rect for each data value
var rect = group.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function(d){
                    return d;
                })
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", function(d, i){
                    return xScale(i);
                })
                .attr("y", function(d){
                    return yScale(d.y0);
                })
                .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
                .attr("height", function(d){
                    return yScale(d.y);
                });

// get data
function getData(data){
    var temp =0,
        tempArr = [];    
    data = [];

    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
        tempArr = [];
        for(var j=0; j<5; j++){
            temp = Math.round(Math.random() *maxValue);
            tempArr.push( { x: j, y: temp });
        }
        data.push(tempArr);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: it looks like there is a typo of ".y0' where you are setting your y value. Is that intentional?

Comment: When using stack() in d3 v3, the return array has y0.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have solved this by now, but it doesn't seem like you are using v3 of d3. The methods your calling seem to be the v4 versions. You might look at https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md to see some of the changes that have been made.

Comment: I give up this problem, and I wait more examples about d3 v4 now. I use some d3 v4 that I know how to use. I don't know what features in v4's stack(), and how to use it.

Comment: There is no `y` or `y0` in D3 v4. Read the docs: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/stack-layout